# Fetch from body return null into controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Why does [FromBody] fetch value always return null value. I have tried everything but nothing has worked, maybe you have a better idea? I am stuck with this code.

This is my JavaScript:

```
const DetailSewa = barangSewa;

  const sewa = {
    NotaSewa: $("#notaSewa").val(),
    PelangganId: $("#cboSearchPelanggan").val(),
    TempatAcara: $("#txtTempatAcara").val(),
    TanggalAcara: $("#txtTanggalAcara").val(),
    OngkosKerja: $("#ongkosKerja").val(),
    OngkosKirim: $("#ongkosKirim").val(),
    OngkosCuci: $("#ongkosCuci").val(),
    SisaBayar: $("#sisaBayar").val(),
    UangMuka: $("#uangMuka").val(),
    TotalBayar: $("#totalBayar").val(),
    TipeDokumen: $("#cboSearchDokumen").val(),
    DetailSewa: DetailSewa,
  };

  $("#btnSimpan").closest("div.card-body").LoadingOverlay("show");

  fetch("/Transaksi/CreateSewaPeralatan", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" },
    body: JSON.stringify(sewa),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      $("#btnSimpan").closest("div.card-body").LoadingOverlay("hide");
      return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response);
    })
    .then((responseJson) => {
      if (responseJson.State) {

        swal("Terdaftar !", "Nota : " + $("#notaSewa").val(), "sukses");
      } else {
        swal("Maaf", "Sewa barang gagal terdaftar", "error");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      $("#btnSimpan").closest("div.card-body").LoadingOverlay("hide");
    });
```

my controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateSewaPeralatan([FromBody] Sewa model)
        {
            ResponseSewa<Sewa> gResponse = new ResponseSewa<Sewa>();
            try
            {
                _transaksiService.CreateSewa(model);

                gResponse.State = true;
                gResponse.Object = model;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                gResponse.State = false;
                gResponse.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, gResponse);
        }
```

My config Json Serialization:

```
services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });
```

I hope the fetch can pass the value into controller

Comment: What error you are getting ? Have you cheked browser console? Aaree you getting any errors there?

Comment: no error in console @MdFaridUddinKiron , data always return null in controller

Comment: If you check console with `sewa` like `console.log(sewa)` what are you getting, In addition, do you any custom configuration for json serialization in your program.cs file?

Comment: Could you please share `Sewa` model details?

Comment: in `console.log(sewa)` all data is there and i set json serialization like this `options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;` @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: This is causing the issue, could you please share your full configuration in your question? I mean full `options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;` in program.cs

Comment: this confguration :
`services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });` @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Not here, update your question with full config.

Comment: I've updated my config Json Serialize in question, that's all @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Okay, thanks wait a while.

Comment: thanks, i'm waiting.. @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Now you can try the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does [FromBody] fetch value always return null value. I have
> tried everything but nothing has worked, maybe you have a better idea?

I have reproduced your issue. You are getting null value on your controller because of your [`options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamingpolicy?view=net-7.0#remarks) I am not sure why you have intented to set it as `null`. Either you should set to `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` if you want to restrict `CamelCase` or just get rid of that.

Set to `null` means if anything doesn't matched it will always be empty. Thus, you are getting null value within your controller. You could modify as following:

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
})
```

**Note:** If you don't want to set [`JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamingpolicy?view=net-7.0#remarks) just ommit or comment the full line.

**Sample Model:**

```
 public class Sewa
        {
         
            public string NotaSewa { get; set; }
            public int PelangganId { get; set; }
            public string TempatAcara { get; set; }
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateSewaPeralatan([FromBody] Sewa model)
        {
           
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
        }
```

**Javascript:**

```
const sewa = {
                NotaSewa: "NotaSewa Value From Client Side",
                PelangganId: 101,
                TempatAcara: "TempatAcara",
            };

            console.log(sewa);

             fetch("http://localhost:5094/JavascriptPost/CreateSewaPeralatan", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" },
                body: JSON.stringify(sewa),
            });
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [JSON property naming policy, you could check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy)

Comment: wow, amazing @MdFaridUddinKiron, thank you so much for your help, this is helpfull, now my code running properly

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you on this.